# How to gather values from every loop in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have sequence of 10 frames. Images have black dots.
What I'm trying to do is saving every centroid co-ordinates (for all dots), but whenever it shows more than one centroid in image I get an error [Error using horzcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.] My question might be stupid because of course the Error is clear and obvious, but still how to save the co-ordinates from every loop?

```
temp = [];

for j = 1:1:10

img = imread('img.tif, j);
grayImg = mat2gray(img);
bwImg = imbinarize(grayImg, Threshold);

s  = regionprops(bwImg, 'centroid');
centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);

temp2 = [temp2, centroids];

end
```

Comment: Maybe something is holding the data from previous step of loop? Can you print the value of `s.Centroid` after first and second iteration of loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N.Cvala,

did you consider using cell arrays (see `help cell`)? I rewrote your code to accommodate that.

```
  nCells = 10;
  temp = cell(1, nCells);
  for j = 1:nCells
        img = imread('img.tif', j);
        grayImg = mat2gray(img);
        bwImg = imbinarize(grayImg, Threshold);
        s = regionprops(bwImg, 'centroid');            
        centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);
        temp{j} = centroids;
  end
  % Access the centroids computed in the first iteration
  temp{1}
```

Cells are nice because they are arrays which allow to store any type of data into them. If you would like a more structured way of store your data you could look into structures (`doc struct`)

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but a link to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) and a description of why cell arrays are useful in this case would make this a better answer.

Comment: You are right, I even pasted into my code, but for some reason I forgot to include it... too hasty

Comment: That worked great! This is exactly what I asked for! Thank you so much! People here are very nice and helpful I can't believe.